# How to sync mail/contacts/calendars from an Outlook.com account using Exchange ActiveSync on Android 4.2.2?

Tags: android, email, outlook, synchronization, outlook.com

I believe I have tried everything but every time I get stuck on "Waiting for sync. Your email will appear soon." After hours of waiting without any calendars/contacts/mail arriving I delete the account.

I have tried creating a "Corporate" account from "Settings/Account". I have also tried creating the account from the "Mail" and the "Contacts" app. The auto configuring "Retrieving account information..." leaves me with the wrong information (outlook.com for server and just /username for "Domain/Username"), so I have to go into "Manual setup". For "Incoming settings" in the "Mail" app I use:

Domain\Username:
\username@outlook.com

Password:
The password

Server:
m.hotmail.com. I have also tried s.outlook.com, m.outlook.com, dub-m.hotmail.com, snt-m.hotmail.com.

Use secure connection (SSL):
Checked

Accept all SSL certificates:
Tried both checked and unchecked

Port:
443

When I click "Done" after having entered this I get "Checking incoming server settings..." and it goes through. After this I'm greeted by the aforementioned "Waiting for sync. Your email will appear soon." and the mail never appears.

Really, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and after a week of not being able to connect I'm starting to give up.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the slightly embarrassing solution. I had turned off system wide auto-sync. With this option off it was impossible to even force syncs of calendars via the Corporate account settings. Even though I got a confirmation it was synced (with time) no email/calendars/contacts ever showed up. Very misleading.